# How to properly use mmv and avoid "no match"

Tags: filenames, mmv

My folders look like this:

```
$ ls
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar  4  2020 cdc-firewall-v1
drwxr-xr-x 2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Mar  4  2020 cdc-firewall-v2
drwxr-xr-x 2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Nov 24 10:40 cdc-firewall-v3
drwxr-xr-x 2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Nov 24 10:43 cdc-firewall-v4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ychaouche ychaouche 4.0K Nov 24 11:17 X
```

I want them to look like this : 1, 2, 3, 4 (get rid of `cdc-firewall-v`)

Here's what I tried:

```
$ mmv "*v*" "#2"
*v* -> #2 : no match.
Nothing done.
```

My reasoning was:

1. For the `from` part

   1. `*` would match cdc-firewall- and be assigned to #1
   2. `v` would match `v`
   3. `*` would match the last number (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) and be assigned to `#2`
2. For the `to` part: replace the whole name with `#2` which would be the number.

Answer (score 2):

mmv refuses to rename folders unless you specify the `-r` option, which worked in my case with same syntax as above :

```
 mmv -r "*v*" "#2"
```